# Can't load geojson file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geojson

I'm trying to load a geoJson file on my map but it isn't working.
Here is my code :

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [57.089460, -2.082101],
        [56.744047, -2.464766],
        [56.977826, -2.720955],
        [57.089460, -2.082101]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

In an initialize function :

```
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
var mapOptions = {
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.975012, -2.343829),
   zoom: 9,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

var localLayer = new google.maps.Data();
localLayer.loadGeoJson('js/coordinates.json');
localLayer.setMap(map);
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong if you see the mistake please.
(the path to my json file is correct)

Comment: Try to load google default file
https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json

If it will work try to change content of your file with data from google.json.

It will help to find what is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run your geoJSON through geojsonlint.com, it is invalid:

> Invalid GeoJSON
>   Line 1: "properties" property required

This validates (but the coordinates are backwards):

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
"properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [57.089460, -2.082101],
        [56.744047, -2.464766],
        [56.977826, -2.720955],
        [57.089460, -2.082101]
      ]
    ]
  }
};
```

with corrected coordinates:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/z3nsctqz/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.975012, -2.343829),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

  var localLayer = new google.maps.Data();
  localLayer.addGeoJson(geoJson);
  localLayer.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var geoJson = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [-2.082101, 57.089460],
        [-2.464766, 56.744047],
        [-2.720955, 56.977826],
        [-2.082101, 57.089460]
      ]
    ]
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A feature object must have a member with the name "properties".[feature-objects](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects).

So it is nullable and you can add `"properties":null` to your feature object.